# passing a parameter from view to controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, smarty

i'm using Smarty and PHP.

I want to pass some parameter from the view to the controller

View

```
<dd><a href="{site_url()}admin/reloadConditions">Pre Registrado</a></dd>
```

Controller

```
public function reloadConditions($cond){
    // some code
}
```

I want to send for example the parameter "1", and tried different ways of doing like:

View

```
<dd><a href="{site_url()}admin/reloadConditions/1">Pre Registrado</a></dd>
```

But nothing seems to work. Is there any chance to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing argumento get to function:

url: admin/reloadConditions/1

```
function index($id)
{
  echo $id; // output 1
}
```

**Guide**: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/controllers.html

**or**

```
function index()
{
  // admin/reloadConditions/1
  // admin = 1
  // reloadConditions = 2

  echo $this->uri->segment(3); // catch third parameter in url
}
```

**Guide**: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, i have very clear that. The thing is that i can't make the opposite: passing FROM the view to the controller.

Comment: You want to get pass parameter to the function?

Comment: As you can see in my code, before you answered me i tried with passing parameters through the function (your first option). Now i have learned thanks to you, another way of doing that (with the uri segment). My code wasn't working because i had wrong paths. Now i corrected it and works super. Obrigado meu amigo!